# Cost to delegate stake to a validator

Tags: staking

I am working on cost analysis for staking. Could you confirm my understanding?

If I want to create a staking wallet and allocate it to a validator, will these be the fees I will incur?

1. Transfer of SOL to a staking wallet
2. Delegation instruction
3. Deactivation instruction
4. withdrawal of funds from staking wallet to my main wallet?

Each transaction will be between 0.000005 SOL and 0.00001 SOL? So in total it will cost me a maximum of 0.00004 SOL.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no congestion fee adjustments apply during any of the transactions, your analysis should be correct for the transaction fee cost. Account creation and delegation can be combined into one transaction and most web wallets do this, which would reduce the sum signatures by one.

Additionally you'll have to carry a rent-exempt-reserve balance in the stake account that will not contribute to the delegation and can be fully recovered when you withdraw to close the account.

```
$ solana -um rent stake
Rent per byte-year: 0.00000348 SOL
Rent per epoch: 0.00000625 SOL
Rent-exempt minimum: 0.00228288 SO
```

Comment: Does it have to be paid per wallet? Is it must have or a wait to reduce some other fees?